# Zend Framework Facebook-like wall plugin

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, plugins

Do you know any plugin for adding a Facebook-like wall to my Zend Framework application?

Comment: Have a look with the name "shootbox" rather than "wall".

Comment: In the italian version it is called **bacheca** (_bulletin board_) :P Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery plugin that provides that functionality.  http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall

If you need to do this all server side you should be able to look through the plugin and extract the appropriate FB api calls that they are using to retrieve the data.